# RESTful generator resource

Tags: rest

I need to create a unique alphanumeric identifier from a given string. It basically makes a string url conform. But it also make it unique by numbering the string.

If there is an article called "Great Article" already with an alphanumeric id `great-article` it will be called `great-article-2`. Easy.

To get that number I simply count the number of articles, which identifier begins with `great-article` and add 1. Easy again.

Currently, I have a REST resource for that, `.../slugs/` which turn the string into the questioned identifier. But I'm pretty sure this is not REST conform. After all I don't like it.

I could request the article from the client `.../articles/?i=great-article` while performing a search and create the identifier in the client.

What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

My one good all time suggestion for these kind of problems is

**Plan A.** Use Current time Ticks with the file name. That will be unique.

If you feel you generate too many articles you can go with the plan B.

**Plan B.** Generate GUID and add it to the file name. This will be 99.999% unique.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Theses 99.999% solutions accumulate in huge projects with wide use to high failure probailities.